# Logging using ning's asyncronous http client library

Tags: java, logging, log4j, asynchttpclient

How do we setup logging using Ning's Asynchronous HTTP client ?
There are no pointers to it in the documentation except the fact that it is dependent on Log4J.
My project uses log4j and below shows the content of our log4j.properties file.

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, STDOUT
log4j.logger.com.ning.http.client=DEBUG
# Configure the Standard Out Appender
log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.STDOUT.target=System.out
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p (%F:%L) %m%n
```

I am aware that ning apache HTTP client uses slf4j for logging and hence we have log4j-over-slf4j.jar on the project classpath instead of log4j.jar.
Please help.

Thanks in advance.